# CommonMark markdown is live

Tags: discussion

As of 2020-06-11, Electrical Engineering site has reportedly been updated to use CommonMark markdown engine. [Migration Schedule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348750/270345)

If any strange formatting issues appear, bugs can be reported on the meta.stackexchange announcement [We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/270345)